# warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates

Tags: macos, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I get this error **warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates** when I cloning repo in local repository [this link](https://github.com/zikula-modules/Scribite/issues/106), [this link](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/269610/sourcetree-git-cloning-warning-templates-not-found), and [this link](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/250260/about-git-path-for-sourcetree) I tried this method and I just waiting more than 20 minutes but repo doesn't clone. I use source-tree and OS X El Capitan. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Create a templates folder.

In your case, it should be: `mkdir /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates`

Comment: I ran into the same error and tried this. But no use.

Comment: you may have to also mkdir of the git folder, share folder etc

Comment: Confirmed this worked for me (sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates && sudo chown -R _my_username_ /usr/local/git) - seems like sourcetree on OSX blindly checks this /usr/local templates path regardless of which git you have installed or which git sourcetree is otherwise successfully using.

Comment: Couldn't use sudo in my machine, so I simply cloned it from git and imported it into sourcetree

Comment: I removed the snap gh and installed apt's gh and it worked

Answer (score 15):

I was also getting same error

```
warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates
```

when I cloning repo in local repository then i found solution which solved my issue.
I Added the [init] section to .gitconfig in home directory, so that it looked at SourceTree's git templates directory when cloning a repo:

```
[init]
templatedir = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/share/git-core/templates
```

Comment: If I may add, and if you're on linux, type: ```whereis git-core``` This one-line command will give you the location/s of your git-core folder.

Answer (score 10):

In case of Source tree on macOS 
Steps:

```
Source tree Menu
Preferences
Git
Click on System Git under Embedded Git Version 2.2.1
Reset to embedded Git
Restart source tree
```

Comment: This had no effect for me - seems like there is just a bug in sourcetree where it always points to the templates path of what would have been a "brew install" git, even if you haven't brew installed git.

Comment: This actually worked for me on macOS 10.12 with SourceTree 2.6.2 -- and without needing to restart SourceTree. I switched to the System git, reinitiated the clone (which now ran without no template error), then switched back. Some old Atlassian [support forum posts](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Git-questions/About-git-path-for-Sourcetree/qaq-p/186483) also describe this as working.

Comment: This solution have no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Rohit's answer, I went into SourceTree's Tools->Options->Git and selected "Update Embedded Git". After the latest Embedded Git version was installed, the warning stopped occurring.

Comment: This worked for me. It was automatically completed after few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

[wonderfulthunk's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877649/warning-templates-not-found-usr-local-git-share-git-core-templates/78065651#comment76921665_36382713) works for me:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates && sudo chown -R my_username /usr/local/git
```

Answer (score 4):

Cloning via SourceTree for Mac, the download was stuck at 99% and I was getting the same error:

> warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates

I started looking up the issue and found this Question. Was about to start with some of the Answers here...

But then it finally completed. So, my Answer: **wait a bit longer.** Mine was cloning for 10 minutes or so.

Comment: i'm getting same error and it took one hour still i can't clone @pkamb is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Absolutely, it may take some more mins, in my case as well, it took around 5-7 mins to get cloned completely. So, I'd recommend to wait for at least sometime for cloning.

Comment: Time didn't make any difference for me. I just clone via command line, then add the now local repo to Sourcetree.

Answer (score 2):

I followed below steps and I am able to get through this issue in Windows 10.

**Step1:**
First know the path of %USERPROFILE% using below command in command prompt.

> echo %USERPROFILE%

Please note that, you can also run **git config --list** and look for init.templatedir for the path.

**Step2:**
Look for .git_template folder in it.
If is missing, please run below command to add it.

> git config --global init.templatedir "%USERPROFILE%.git_template

**Step3:**
Create a folder namely templates in it.

After creating this templates folder, I did not get the warning mentioned i.e. 'templates not found' any more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened because an unaccesed project. Check that you have all the privileges to clone that repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sourcetree application, switch git version from "Embedded Git" to "System Git" in setting.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/About-git-path-for-Sourcetree/qaq-p/186483

And after changing git version, if you still have problem with cloning, change protocol from "ssh" to "https".

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get past this problem. Even after getting rid of the 'templates not found' error by adding the usr/local/git... folder, the clone would still look like it was at 99% and sit there for HOURS. I just clone via command line and it's there in seconds, then I just add the local repo to Sourcetree instead.

Answer (score 0):

**MacOS: Ventura 13.0 /
Sourcetree: 4.2.0**

I fixed **warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates** by going to "Sourcetree preferences -> Git" and clicking to "Use System Git". There's no need to restart Sourcetree, just try to clone again.
I didn't switch to usage of embedded Git again, all works perfectly with usage of System Git.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The right info is in many of these answers, but I'm going to try to summarize it all together a bit more.  The "just make the dir" answer was not what I needed because I need to know what a template dir is and if I want that.

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) for what a template directory is is:

> Files and directories in the template directory whose name do not start with a dot will be copied to the $GIT_DIR after it is created.

In there, it includes `init.templateDir` as one of the values it will use. Unfortunately, to specify the value, you do not use the string `init.templateDir` in your config file but have to know that this means your Git config (`~/.gitconfig`) has a section called `init` and an attribute called `templateDir`, like so:

```
[init]
  templateDir=«some path»
```

(I guess you can do `git config --global init.templateDir «some path»` to set the value from the command line)

So that `«some path»` needs to exist *or* you need to remove `templateDir` from the init section.

If you `~/.gitconfig` doesn't have this set, you can try running `git config init.templateDir` and see what it produces.  If it shows a value, that means some global configuration somewhere has set it and you will either have to edit that or create the directory.  The man page for `git config` is not for the faint of heart, but there is a section titled `FILES` that outlines what config files it will use.

Understanding that section requires careful reading of the man page to understand what stuff like `$(prefix)` and `$GIT_DIR` actually reference.  Godspeed if this is what you have to do.

I did try to put stuff in `«some path»` to see what template dir actually does, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Presumably it's a feature that really does work but I couldn't figure it out based on the docs.