# Cannot clone git repo - Templates not found

Tags: git, macos, atlassian-sourcetree

I am getting an error when attempting to clone a git repo using attlassian source tree stating

```
error: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates
```

A quick google search shows a few solutions to this issue, but none have worked for me.

When I do attempt to clone a repo, the installation will never complete. 
Any ideas how I can fix this?

EDIT:

I tried all solutions stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877649/warning-templates-not-found-usr-local-git-share-git-core-templates)

Comment: Can you state *what* the solutions were and which ones you tried?

Comment: I edited my question. When attempting to create the templates folder, I was told I do not have permission. @NilsWerner

Comment: Have you tried `sudo`?

Comment: yes, and then I get the error
    /usr/local/git/share/git-core: No such file or directory

@NilsWerner

Comment: Do all the directories leading up to `/usr/local/git/share/git-core` exist?

Comment: /git/ does not exist..... No idea how this happened@NilsWerner

Comment: Try reinstalling it using homebrew `brew install git` (the path suggests Git is from homebrew). If you're not using homebrew, see if you can set Source Tree to use a different `git` binary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877649/warning-templates-not-found-usr-local-git-share-git-core-templates)